# How to use Scheme instead of Python in Sage Math

Tags: python, math, scheme, sage

Unlike commercial mathematics apps, Sage Math uses Python as its scripting language. I don't like it because it doesn't have tail recursion, isn't homoiconic, and uses indentation to put out statement blocks. How can I use another language like Scheme instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't like Python you can [use](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/594/call-cc-code) [C/C++](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/tutorial/programming.html#creating-compiled-code) or [Fortran](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/numerical_sage/f2py.html). Sage is built around Python / Cython libraries, with little interoperability with other programming languages in mind.

Or you could use a Scheme interpreter that compiles to C (say, [Chicken Scheme](http://www.call-cc.org/) or [Gambit Scheme](http://dynamo.iro.umontreal.ca/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)) and somehow call the generated code from Sage, in principle it should be possible. But why bother? give Python a try, you'll discover that it's quite a nice language to work with, with many [scientific libraries](http://www.talyarkoni.org/blog/2013/11/18/the-homogenization-of-scientific-computing-or-why-python-is-steadily-eating-other-languages-lunch/) and applications.

Comment: I have already tried Python and was scared of it's syntax and inflexibility.

Comment: @LinuxDistance this is off-topic, but... I disliked Python's syntax at first, but after a while you get used to it. I love how little code I have to write to do something, and it's very readable: this is a consequence of its "inflexibility", and it's a good thing! There should be one, and preferably [only one](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), obvious way to do things. And it's more [similar to Lisp](http://norvig.com/python-lisp.html) than you believe. Also, it lends itself very well for writing code in a [functional programming](http://ua.pycon.org/static/talks/kachayev) style

Comment: Good answer!  I'll just add that it's also possible to use some Fortran, and that Python as the base is seen as a plus, not minus, for many users (as compared to other mathematics software).

Comment: @kcrisman I wasn't aware of Fortran interoperability, I updated my answer, thanks!

Comment: Don't be afraid of the syntax. As long as you don't mix spaces and tabs in indent. You should not have problems. Keep in mind that blocks by ident is just a way to define expression. This [srfi](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-49/srfi-49.html) implement a style that is quite close to python.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from Sage, you could try Maxima [1], which is implemented in Common Lisp -- you can easily write additional programs in CL and integrate them with Maxima.

Maxima has its own programming language which has Lisp-like features (e.g. homoiconic) but to be honest, the programming language is kind of clumsy.

[1] http://sourceforge.net/p/maxima, http://maxima.sourceforge.net